# lxml tree connection and properties

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a `.dtsx` file so, I have multiple components with connections, so I need to extract component that have especific connection, but I can not handle that, example:

```xml
<components>
    <component refId="Component_1 Name" componentClassID="componentClassID" contactInfo="contactInfo" description="description" name="name" usesDispositions="true" version="6">
        <properties>
            <property dataType="System.String" description="description" expressionType="Notify" name="SqlCommandParam" UITypeEditor="UITypeEditor">QUERY THAT i NEED TO GET</property>
        </properties>
        <connections>
            <connection refId="Name" connectionManagerID="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]" connectionManagerRefId="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]" description="description" name="OleDbConnection" />
        </connections>
    </component>
    <component refId="Component_2 Name" componentClassID="componentClassID" contactInfo="contactInfo" description="description" name="PartnerService" usesDispositions="true" version="6">
        <properties>
            <property dataType="System.String" description="description" expressionType="Notify" name="SqlCommandParam" UITypeEditor="UITypeEditor">QUERY THAT I DONT NEED TO GET</property>
        </properties>
        <connections>
            <connection refId="Name" connectionManagerID="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_STG]" connectionManagerRefId="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_STG]" description="description" name="OleDbConnection" />
        </connections>
    </component>
</components>
```

I need to get the query where `connectionManagerID="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]"` But I cannot handle that because they are in the same level, properties and connections

Code that I am using is +/- like:

```py
for cnt, element in enumerate(root.xpath(".//*")):
    if cnt == 0:
        file = root.attrib["{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}ObjectName"]
        data["file_name"] = file + ".dtsx"
    if element.tag == con_tag:
        if element.attrib.get("{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}ObjectName"):
            if element.attrib.get("{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}ObjectName", None) == "BI_SYNC":
                conn_name = element.attrib.get("{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}ObjectName", None)
                conn_dtsid = element.attrib.get("{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}DTSID", None)
                data["conn_name"] = conn_name
                data["conn_dtsid"] = conn_dtsid
    if element.tag == exec_tag:
        for cnt_0, element_0 in enumerate(element):
            if element_0.tag == execs_tag:
                for cnt_1, element_1 in enumerate(element_0): # Get package name
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your **exact** expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Since `properties` and `connections` are both children of the same `component`, you can use xpath to select the `component` based on the `connection`, then select the `property`.

So instead of a lot of nested if and for statements, try something like...

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = """<root xmlns="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts">
    <components>
        <component refId="Component_1 Name" componentClassID="componentClassID" contactInfo="contactInfo" description="description" name="name" usesDispositions="true" version="6">
            <properties>
                <property dataType="System.String" description="description" expressionType="Notify" name="SqlCommandParam" UITypeEditor="UITypeEditor">QUERY THAT i NEED TO GET</property>
            </properties>
            <connections>
                <connection refId="Name" connectionManagerID="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]" connectionManagerRefId="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]" description="description" name="OleDbConnection"/>
            </connections>
        </component>
        <component refId="Component_2 Name" componentClassID="componentClassID" contactInfo="contactInfo" description="description" name="PartnerService" usesDispositions="true" version="6">
            <properties>
                <property dataType="System.String" description="description" expressionType="Notify" name="SqlCommandParam" UITypeEditor="UITypeEditor">QUERY THAT I DONT NEED TO GET</property>
            </properties>
            <connections>
                <connection refId="Name" connectionManagerID="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_STG]" connectionManagerRefId="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_STG]" description="description" name="OleDbConnection"/>
            </connections>
        </component>
    </components>
</root>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)

ns = {"dts": "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"}

for property_elem in root.xpath(".//dts:component[dts:connections/dts:connection[@connectionManagerID='Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]']]/dts:properties/dts:property", namespaces=ns):
    print(etree.tostring(property_elem).decode())
```

This outputs the following to show that it selects the correct `property`...

```xml
<property xmlns="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" dataType="System.String" description="description" expressionType="Notify" name="SqlCommandParam" UITypeEditor="UITypeEditor">QUERY THAT i NEED TO GET</property>
```

A couple of notes...

- I added a `root` element with the default namespace so my `root` variable would work similar to what you already have.
- I use the `namespaces` kwarg so I could use a prefix in my xpath instead of using Clark notation. (Cleaner in my opinion.)

Comment: I am trying to get `<component refId="Component_1 Name"` but without succes, I need to get all component name, that match with query that I need to get, do you know how to handle that?? Thanks :)