# lxml tree connection name and properties

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a `.dtsx` file so, I have multiple components with connections, so I need to extract component that have especific connection, but I can not handle that, example:

```xml
<components>
    <component refId="Component_1 Name" componentClassID="componentClassID" contactInfo="contactInfo" description="description" name="name" usesDispositions="true" version="6">
        <properties>
            <property dataType="System.String" description="description" expressionType="Notify" name="SqlCommandParam" UITypeEditor="UITypeEditor">QUERY THAT i NEED TO GET</property>
        </properties>
        <connections>
            <connection refId="Name" connectionManagerID="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]" connectionManagerRefId="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]" description="description" name="OleDbConnection" />
        </connections>
    </component>
    <component refId="Component_2 Name" componentClassID="componentClassID" contactInfo="contactInfo" description="description" name="PartnerService" usesDispositions="true" version="6">
        <properties>
            <property dataType="System.String" description="description" expressionType="Notify" name="SqlCommandParam" UITypeEditor="UITypeEditor">QUERY THAT I DONT NEED TO GET</property>
        </properties>
        <connections>
            <connection refId="Name" connectionManagerID="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_STG]" connectionManagerRefId="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_STG]" description="description" name="OleDbConnection" />
        </connections>
    </component>
</components>
```

I need to get the query where `connectionManagerID="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]"` But I cannot handle that because they are in the same level, properties and connections

Code that I am using is +/- like:

```py
for cnt, element in enumerate(root.xpath(".//*")):
    if cnt == 0:
        file = root.attrib["{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}ObjectName"]
        data["file_name"] = file + ".dtsx"
    if element.tag == con_tag:
        if element.attrib.get("{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}ObjectName"):
            if element.attrib.get("{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}ObjectName", None) == "BI_SYNC":
                conn_name = element.attrib.get("{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}ObjectName", None)
                conn_dtsid = element.attrib.get("{www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts}DTSID", None)
                data["conn_name"] = conn_name
                data["conn_dtsid"] = conn_dtsid
    if element.tag == exec_tag:
        for cnt_0, element_0 in enumerate(element):
            if element_0.tag == execs_tag:
                for cnt_1, element_1 in enumerate(element_0): # Get package name
```

---

## Edit 1

I am trying to get `<component refId="Component_1 Name"` but without succes, I need to get all component name, that match with query that I need to get, do you know how to handle that?? Thanks :)

Comment: This question looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71666803/407651.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get the query where `connectionManagerID="Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]"`

XPath is your friend:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

ns = {
    "dts" = "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
}

root = ET.parse("your_dts.dtsx")

property = root.xpath("""
    //dts:component[
        dts:connections/dts:connection[
            @connectionManagerID = "Package.ConnectionManagers[BI_SYNC]"
        ]
    ]/dts:properties/dts:property[@name = "SqlCommandParam"]
""", namespaces=ns)

if len(property):
    print(property[0].text)
else:
    print("not found")
```

prints

```
QUERY THAT i NEED TO GET
```

Comment: But, how can I get the `<component refId="Component_1 Name"` Component_1 Name??  Print should be something like: `Component_1 Name: QUERY THAT i NEED TO GET`

Comment: @OracyMartos Analyze what the XPath in my answer does, and you will know.